# vba excel rows to xml output on different output folder

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Hello i have made a VBA macro that creates one xml file per row. The problem is that the xml files where created in the default folder location "C:\Users\Dell\Documents" how can i change the default out put directory?

```
Sub xmlPerRow()

 sTemplateXML = _
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + "<data>" + vbNewLine + "<Grai>" + vbNewLine + "</Grai>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <DayDateOut>" + vbNewLine + "   </DayDateOut>" + vbNewLine + "   <Filler>" + vbNewLine + "   </Filler>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <FillerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   </FillerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   <Retailer>" + vbNewLine + "   </Retailer>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <RetailerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   </RetailerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   <Days>" + vbNewLine + "   </Days>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <DayBack>" + vbNewLine + "   </DayBack>" + vbNewLine + "   <DateIn>" + vbNewLine + "   </DateIn>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <BrokenCode>" + vbNewLine + "   </BrokenCode>" + vbNewLine + "   <Broken>" + vbNewLine + "   </Broken>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <TotalCycles>" + vbNewLine + "   </TotalCycles>" + vbNewLine + "</data>" + vbNewLine

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
   sFile = "Grai_" & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & ".xml"
   Dim sGrai As String
   sGrai = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value)
   sDayDateOut = .Cells(lRow, 2).Value
   sFiller = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value
   sFillerCountry = .Cells(lRow, 4).Value
   sRetailer = .Cells(lRow, 5).Value
   sRetailerCountry = .Cells(lRow, 6).Value
   sDays = .Cells(lRow, 7).Value
   sDayBack = .Cells(lRow, 8).Value
   sDateIn = .Cells(lRow, 9).Value
   sBrokenCode = .Cells(lRow, 10).Value
   sBroken = .Cells(lRow, 11).Value
   sTotalCycles = .Cells(lRow, 12).Value

   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Grai")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sGrai)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DayDateOut")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDayDateOut)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Filler")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sFiller)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("RetailerCountry")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sRetailerCountry)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Retailer")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sRetailer)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Days")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDays)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DayBack")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDayBack)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DateIn")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDateIn)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("BrokenCode")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sBrokenCode)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Broken")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sBroken)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("TotalCycles")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTotalCycles)
   doc.Save sFile
  Next

 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `sFile = "\\server_path\folder\subfolder\Grai_" & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & ".xml"`

Comment: Thanks Scott, this works!! It is to obvious, i feel realy stuppid ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of Scott, here the adjusted answer:

```
Sub xmlPerRow()

 sTemplateXML = _
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + "<data>" + vbNewLine + "<Grai>" + vbNewLine + "</Grai>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <DayDateOut>" + vbNewLine + "   </DayDateOut>" + vbNewLine + "   <Filler>" + vbNewLine + "   </Filler>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <FillerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   </FillerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   <Retailer>" + vbNewLine + "   </Retailer>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <RetailerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   </RetailerCountry>" + vbNewLine + "   <Days>" + vbNewLine + "   </Days>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <DayBack>" + vbNewLine + "   </DayBack>" + vbNewLine + "   <DateIn>" + vbNewLine + "   </DateIn>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <BrokenCode>" + vbNewLine + "   </BrokenCode>" + vbNewLine + "   <Broken>" + vbNewLine + "   </Broken>" + vbNewLine + _
        "   <TotalCycles>" + vbNewLine + "   </TotalCycles>" + vbNewLine + "</data>" + vbNewLine

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
   sFile = "c:\GraiData\Grai_" & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & ".xml"
   Dim sGrai As String
   sGrai = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value)
   sDayDateOut = .Cells(lRow, 2).Value
   sFiller = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value
   sFillerCountry = .Cells(lRow, 4).Value
   sRetailer = .Cells(lRow, 5).Value
   sRetailerCountry = .Cells(lRow, 6).Value
   sDays = .Cells(lRow, 7).Value
   sDayBack = .Cells(lRow, 8).Value
   sDateIn = .Cells(lRow, 9).Value
   sBrokenCode = .Cells(lRow, 10).Value
   sBroken = .Cells(lRow, 11).Value
   sTotalCycles = .Cells(lRow, 12).Value

   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Grai")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sGrai)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DayDateOut")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDayDateOut)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Filler")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sFiller)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("RetailerCountry")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sRetailerCountry)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Retailer")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sRetailer)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Days")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDays)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DayBack")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDayBack)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DateIn")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDateIn)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("BrokenCode")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sBrokenCode)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("Broken")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sBroken)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("TotalCycles")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTotalCycles)
   doc.Save sFile
  Next

 End With
End Sub
```