# Excel to XML export via VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, export

I have been using the template in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098966/convert-rows-of-spreadsheet-to-separate-xml-files) in order to export data from an Excel spreadsheet into separate XML files for each row. I've modified the template in that post to match the output I need, yet when I run the macro I get a "Runtime Error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set." Here is the VBA Macro I'm currently using:

```
Sub xmlconverter1()

sTemplateXML = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
"<mods xmlns='http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3' xmlns:mods='http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <titleInfo>" + vbNewLine + _
    "       <title></title>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </titleInfo>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <typeOfResource>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </typeOfResource>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <name type='personal'>" + vbNewLine + _
    "       <namePart></namePart>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </name>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <abstract>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </abstract>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <identifier>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </identifier>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <originInfo>" + vbNewLine + _
    "       <dateIssued></dateIssued>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </originInfo>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <physicalDescription>" + vbNewLine + _
    "       <form></form>" + vbNewLine + _
    "       <extent></extent>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   <subject>" + vbNewLine + _
    "       <geographic></geographic>" + vbNewLine + _
    "   </subject>" + vbNewLine + _
    "</mods>" + vbNewLine


 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
 sTitle = .Cells(lRow, 2).Value
 sType = .Cells(lRow, 11).Value
 sCreator = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value
 sDescription = .Cells(lRow, 6).Value
 sIdentifier = .Cells(lRow, 1).Value
 sDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 9).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
 sForm = .Cells(lRow, 12).Value
 sExtent = .Cells(lRow, 22).Value
 sCoverage = .Cells(lRow, 7).Value
 doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
 doc.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTitle)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("typeOfResource")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sType)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("name")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sCreator)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("abstract")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDescription)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("identifier")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sIdentifier)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("dateIssued")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDate)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sForm)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("extent")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sExtent)
 doc.getElementsByTagName("geographic")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sCoverage)
 doc.Save sIdentifier

Next

 End With

End Sub
```

What can I change that will get rid of this error and still give me the output in the format I need?

Comment: What line gives the error?

Answer (score 2):

```
doc.validateOnParse = False
```

is hiding the parse error:

> End tag 'mods' does not match the start tag 'physicalDescription'.

You haven't closed the tag `<physicalDescription>` in your XML template

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it! The debugger was pointing to the first "doc.get ElementsbyTagName" line, so I assumed it was having trouble reading the XML template for the tags. Should've known it was something simpler!